# A property of the Volterra operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I was reading a paper and I came across the Volterra operator $$(Vf)(x)=\int ^x _0 f(t) dt$$
And its adjoint $$(V^*f)(x)=\int^1 _x f(t) dt$$

It also says that a simple and useful identity is $$V+V^*=P$$

Where $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto constant functions.

How can I prove that $V+V^*$ is an orthogonal projection?

How to I determine the subspace onto which it projects?

Comment: Which paper is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $S=V+V^*$ then $S:L^2(0,1) \to L^2(0,1)$ is a bounded operator. First we show that $S$ is idempotent ($S^2=S$). Let $f \in L^2(0,1)$:
\begin{align*}
S^2f = S(Sf) &= S(\int_0^x f(t)dt + \int_x^1 f(t)dt) \\& = S\left(\int_0^1 f(t)dt\right) \\ &= \int_0^x\int_0^1 f(t) dt + \int_x^1 \int_0^1 f(t)dt)\\ &=\int_0^1f(t)dt=Sf\end{align*}
So $S$ is idempotent.
Next we show that $S$ is selfadjoint. Let $f,g \in L^2(0,1)$:
\begin{align*}
&(Sf,g) = \int_0^1\left( \int_0^1 f(s)ds\right)g(t)dt = \left(\int_0^1 f(t)dt\right)\left( \int_0^1 g(t)dt\right) \\
&(f,Sg) = \int_0^1f(t)\left( \int_0^1 g(s)ds\right)dt = \left(\int_0^1 f(t)dt\right)\left( \int_0^1 g(t)dt\right)
\end{align*}
So $S=S^*$. This is sufficient for $S$ to be an orthogonal project.

(Showing $S=S^*$ can be done easier by seeing that $S^* = (V+V^*)^* = V^* + V^{**} = V+V^*=S$

Comment: why do we have to show it is idempotent?

Comment: @Aljabra That the definition of a(n) orthogonal projection.

Comment: you know the $f,g \in L^2 (0,1)$ you have used, are they arbitrary $f,g$?

Comment: @Aljabra Yes, they can be anything as long as the integral of the squared function over $(0,1)$ is finite.